How can we show that these processes are conditionally independent?
Let

$(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
$Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$
$(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the Metropolis-Hastings chain and proposal sequence of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and acceptance function $\alpha$ and $$Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$

By construction, there is a $[0,1)$-valued independent identically $\mathcal U_{[0,\;1)}$-distributed process $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that

$(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ and $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ are independent
$$X_n=\begin{cases}Y_n&\text{, if }U_n<\alpha(Z_n)\\ X_{n-1}&\text{, otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Now let $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_k:=\inf\{n>\tau_{k-1}:U_n<\alpha(Z_n)\}$$ denote the time at which the $k$th proposal is accepted.
Question: Let $k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $\tau_k<\infty$. How can we show that $\left(U_{\tau_k+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $\left(Y_{\tau_k+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are conditionally independent given $\tau_k$?
Intuitively, the claim seems to be true. But how can we prove it rigorously? It should be enough to show that for all $m\in\mathbb N_0$, $n\in\mathbb N$, $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal E$ the probabilities $$\operatorname P\left[U_{m+1}\in A_1,\ldots,U_{m+n}\in A_n,Y_{m+1}\in B_1,\ldots,Y_{m+n}\in B_n,\tau_k=m\right]\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname P\left[U_{m+1}\in A_1,\ldots,U_{m+n}\in A_n,\tau_k=m\right]\operatorname P\left[Y_{m+1}\in B_1,\ldots,Y_{m+n}\in B_n,\tau_k=m\right]\tag2$$ coincide (correct me, if I'm wrong and that's not sufficient).

Are there any conditions on $X_0$ or can it be chosen to be anything in the support of $X$? (Not sure if it will affect my answer, but I wanted to check)

And to be clear, the statement is a "for any" $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ with finite $\tau_k$, not a "there exists" $k$ statement?

@Alex $X_0$ can be arbitrary. And yes, I want to show the claim for any $k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $\tau_k<\infty$.

I don't understand the claim in the statement of the question that $(U_1, \dots, U_n), (Z_1, \dots, Z_n)$ are independent. Consider the following scenario:
The target distribution is $V \sim Geom(0.99)$, so $P[V = v] = 0.99 \cdot 0.01^{v-1}$ for $v=1, 2, \dots$. Let $$Q(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{y = x + 1} + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{y = x-1} \textrm{ if } x > 1\textrm{, and }\delta_{y = 2} \textrm{ if } x = 1,$$
so given $X_n = x > 1$, $Y_{n + 1}$ is equally likely to be $x - 1$ or $x + 1$, and given $X_n = 1, Y_{n + 1} = 2$.
If $X_n > 2$, then $\alpha((X_n, X_n + 1))$ is given by $$\min\left\{1, \frac{0.99 \cdot 0.01^{X_n + 1}}{0.99 \cdot0.01^{X_n}} \frac{1/2}{1/2}\right\} = \min\left\{1, 0.01\right\} = 0.01.$$
Now suppose $n = 3$ and we observe $(Z_1, \dots, Z_n) = ((X_0, Y_1), (X_1, Y_2), (X_2, Y_3)) = ((5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8))$. Then we know that the three increase moves were proposed, and the first two were accepted, so $U_1, U_2$ must both be less than $0.01$, so the $Z$ and $U$ values are not independent.
If we choose $k=0$ then we can make the exact same argument that $(U_1, U_2, \dots)$ and $(Y_1, Y_2, \dots)$ are not independent. If we observe $2 < Y_1 + 1 = Y_2, Y_2 + 1 = Y_3, Y_3 + 1 = Y_4,$ then we know that the $U$ values must be less than $0.01$. Therefore a probability like $P[U_1 > 0.5, U_2 > 0.5, U_3 > 0.5, 2 < Y_1 + 1 = Y_2, Y_2 + 1 = Y_3] = 0$, but $P[U_1 > 0.5, U_2 > 0.5, U_3 > 0.5]P[2 < Y_1 + 1 = Y_2, Y_2 + 1 = Y_3] > 0$.

$U_n$ is used to determine whether $Y_n$ is accepted (i.e. $Y_n=X_n$), but $Z_n$ does contain $X_{n-1}$; not $X_n$.

yes, that's why I used $(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3) = ((X_0, Y_1), (X_1, Y_2), (X_2, Y_3))$

When you say that $(U_1, \dots, U_n)$ and $(Z_1, \dots, Z_n)$ are independent, do you mean that each individually each $U_i$ is independent of each $Z_i$? I would agree with that statement, but not the independence of the two vectors of observations. $(Z_1, \dots, Z_n)$ tells us every proposal and if it was accepted (apart from if $Y_n$ was accepted), so it must depend on $(U_1, \dots U_n)$ - if the $U_i$s are low then we will do lots of exploring and if they are high then we will only see moves that increase the target distribution.

And in the same way, the $Y$ values and $U$ values can't be independent. If we observed $Y_1=6, Y_2=7, Y_3=8$ in the example I gave then we know that the $U_1, U_2$ must both be less than $0.01$ or it would be impossible to view that sequence of proposals

What I mean is that $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ and $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$, considered as random variables $\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ and $\Omega\to E^n$, respectively, are independent.

However, I see your point. I made a mistake in my description. It should be $Y$ in place of $Z$. Or, maybe even more restrictive, only $(U_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ and $Y_n$ are independent for all $n\in\mathbb N$. I need to think about that.

I think the strongest we can say is that $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is independent of $(U_k)_{k\ge n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Please note that I'm just trying to get the right independence from the description of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to proceed with my actual question.
